# Filter entries that start with string (str_detect)

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

## Filter entries that start with string

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## Fake data

```
Code <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
Info <- c("test", "shop for test", "test", "shop group for test", "test", "test shop for test")
dd <- data.frame(Code, Info)
rm(Code, Info)
```

## Desired output

[image: Two entries. Desired output.]

## Code attempt

```
tt <- dd %>%
  filter(str_detect(Info, "^shop for | shop group for")) #it should generate two entries
```

Comment: It is always advised to add sample of input and sample of output in your post with code tags, kindly do so.

Comment: The problem is the space after ( `| `) the regex will be looking for `" shop group for"` instead of for `"shop group for"`. if you use "^shop for|shop group for") it will return 2 entries.

Comment: @phiver. This comments solves the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As there is a clear pattern in your data, you can use `substr` to look for the word `'shop'` at the beginning. Turn it into a logical, and subset the dataframe.

```
dd[substr(dd[,2], 1, 4)=='shop',]

  Code                Info
2    b       shop for test
4    d shop group for test
```